# Draw 4 quadrants in a Button and change each one's background with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

How can I go about *splitting* a `WPF` Button into *4 quadrants* and customize it so that I can **set Background Color binding for each quadrant separately** with Binding Path to separate properties.

It is nice if Button ***also*** has property to control whether each quadrant is clickable or only one click event is raised as a whole for each quadrant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that if you are talking about binding, then you are using MVVM pattern

In the View-XAML create a button and add 4 rectangles within the content of the button.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="150" Height="150" Command="{Binding RectangleButtonClick}">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SecondQuad" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding SecondQuadColor}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FirstQuad" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding FirstQuadColor}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="ThirdQuad" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding ThirdQuadColor}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FourthQuad" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding FourthQuadColor}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

In your ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private SolidColorBrush _FirstQuadColor;
    public SolidColorBrush FirstQuadColor
    { 
       get { return _FirstQuadColor; }
       set { _FirstQuadColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstQuadColor"); }
    }

private SolidColorBrush _SecondQuadColor;
public SolidColorBrush SecondQuadColor
{
   get { return _SecondQuadColor; }
   set { _SecondQuadColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("SecondQuadColor"); }
}

private SolidColorBrush _ThirdQuadColor;
public SolidColorBrush ThirdQuadColor
{
  get { return _ThirdQuadColor; }
  set { _ThirdQuadColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("ThirdQuadColor"); }
}

private SolidColorBrush _FourthQuadColor;
public SolidColorBrush FourthQuadColor
{
   get { return _FourthQuadColor; }
   set { _FourthQuadColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("FourthQuadColor"); }
}

private ICommand _RectangleButtonClick;
public ICommand RectangleButtonClick
{
   get { return _RectangleButtonClick; }
   set { _RectangleButtonClick = value; OnPropertyChanged("RectangleButtonClick"); }
}

public MyViewModel()
{
   RectangleButtonClick = new DelegateCommand(RectangleButtonClick_Execute);
   FirstQuadColor = Brushes.Red;
   SecondQuadColor = Brushes.Green;
   ThirdQuadColor = Brushes.Blue;
   FourthQuadColor = Brushes.Yellow;
}

    void RectangleButtonClick_Execute()
    {
        var directlyOver = Mouse.DirectlyOver;
        if (directlyOver is Rectangle)
        {
            var selectedRectangle = (directlyOver as Rectangle);

            switch (selectedRectangle.Name)
            {
                case "FirstQuad" : Console.Write("First Quad clicked"); break;
                case "SecondQuad": Console.Write("Second Quad clicked"); break;
                case "ThirdQuad": Console.Write("Third Quad clicked"); break;
                case "FourthQuad": Console.Write("Fourth Quad clicked"); break;
            }

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are actually lots of different ways to do this, the best method will depend on the specifics of your implementation. I'll provide one method here but be advised it's by no means the best (particularly if you're doing MVVM, which you should be).

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Margin="93,92,68,77" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="{Binding Brush00}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown_1"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Fill="{Binding Brush01}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown_2"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Fill="{Binding Brush10}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown_3"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="{Binding Brush11}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown_4" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

And then in the code behind:

```
public partial class MyParentWindow : Window
{
    public MyParentWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyButton.DataContext = new ButtonModel();
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseDown_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseDown_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseDown_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseDown_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class ButtonModel
{
    public Brush Brush00 { get { return Brushes.Red; } }
    public Brush Brush01 { get { return Brushes.Green; } }
    public Brush Brush10 { get { return Brushes.Blue; } }
    public Brush Brush11 { get { return Brushes.Yellow; } }
}
```